# Qiskit: What is the corrrect equilibrium distribution in the thermal relaxation error?

Tags: qiskit

In Qiskit, temperature is a parameter for simulating gate errors in a noise model from backend properties. It is used to calculate the equilibrium state of thermal relaxation errors by `_excited_population(freq, temperature)`. Here frequency is the energy gap between the excited state and the ground state of the qubit and is approximately 5 GHz.
In thermal equlibrium the exited state population should have a distribution according to Maxwell-Boltzmann statistics of the two level system:
$$
p_1 = \frac{e^{-E_1/k_B T }}{e^{-E_0/k_B T }+e^{-E_1/k_B T }} = \frac{1}{e^{\Delta E/k_B T }+1} = \frac{1}{e^{h f/k_B T }+1} .
$$
In Qiskit we find however `# excited state population = 1/(1+exp((2*h*f*1e9)/(kb*T*1e-3)))` where frequency f is measured in GHz and temperature T in mK. Interestingly, the factor 2 is found [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.104.062432) as well, giving $p_1 \approx 10^{-14}$ (with f=5 GHz, T=15 mK), while the above definition applies in a [paper cited there](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.240501), which in turn gives $p_1 \approx 10^{-7}$.

So where does the factor 2 come from or is this an error in both cases?